# How to post data to servlet from java?

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have android app which gets the data from servlet. Now I want to create one more client which will create some data and post it to servlet, then I'd retrieve that on Android. This is my code to get information on Android from servlet:

```
     final RestClient client = new RestClient("App Engine name");

    client.AddParam("hi", "how are you?");

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);


                    try
                    {
                        client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        textView.setText(e.getMessage());

                    }
                    String response = client.getResponse();
                    textView.setText(response);
```

Is there any way I can post data from one more client to servlet and then get it on Android using client.getResponse(); ?

Comment: RequestMethod.POST is a good start ;) Also I would advise doing all this in an asynctask or else you will get an ANR

Comment: I tried to create doPost method same as doGet. And then created one java class which has almost everything same like above code. I am new to this, so I am confused and don't know what to do. I tried searching online to send data to servlet from java, but couldn't find even any example. I would really appreciate if you could help me with this.